# Check coordinate point between two points

Tags: javascript, google-maps, coordinates

I need to verify if a coordinate LAT/LNG point is between other two points (a segment line like a road).
I followed [THIS topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581738/check-if-a-point-projected-on-a-line-segment-is-not-outside-it) with no success.

```
function inRange(start, point, end) {
    start_x = start.lat();
    start_y = start.lng();
    end_x = end.lat();
    end_y = end.lng();
    point_x = point.lat();
    point_y = point.lng();

    var dx = end_x - start_x;
    var dy = end_y - start_y;
    var innerProduct = (point_x - start_x)*dx + (point_y - start_y)*dy;
    return 0 <= innerProduct && innerProduct <= dx*dx + dy*dy;
}


function checkRange(start, point, end){
    var x1 = start.lat();
    var y1 = start.lng();
    var x2 = end.lat();
    var y2 = end.lng();
    var x = point.lat();
    var y = point.lng();

    if (x1 == x2) {  // special case
        return y1 < y2 ? (y1 <= y && y <= y2) : (y2 <= y && y <= y1);
    }

    var m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
    var r1 = x1 + m * y1;
    var r2 = x2 + m * y2;
    var r = x + m * y;
    return r1 < r2 ? (r1 <= r && r <= r2) : (r2 <= r && r <= r1);
}
```

- First test

Start: (44.4963217, 11.327993300000003)

End: (44.4973624, 11.32760170000006)

Point (44.4958434, 11.328122000000008)

InRange == false (OK)
So Point becomes new start Point

- Second test

Start: (44.4958434, 11.328122000000008)

End: (44.4973624, 11.32760170000006)

Point: (44.4966928, 11.32781620000003)

InRange == false (ERROR)
Point2 is between start/end but the function returns false :(

Comment: I feel like you've over complicated this. Forgetting the 'special case' for the moment: what does `return (point.lat() < end.lat() && point.lat() > start.lat() && point.lng() < end.lng() && point.lng > start.lng());` return?

Comment: Your longitudinal point on the second test is not between the start and end longitudes. `(11.32781620000003 < 11.32760170000006 && 11.32781620000003 > 11.328122000000008)` returns false.

Comment: True, but if you check on GMaps you'll see that second test point is on the road between start and end points.

Comment: That's academic. The point is that your method is responding to the variables you've passed it as it should do. The problem, then, is with GMaps rendering or calculation of the position.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is responding as it should given the data you've passed it:

```
var start_lng = 11.328122000000008;

var end_lng = 11.32760170000006; // This longitude is less than the point longitude.

var point_lng = 11.32781620000003; // This longitude more than the end longitude.
```

Comment: Agree on that. Any ideas on a working algorithm for this issue?

Comment: You'll have to go into a bit more detail about how you're getting the data and why you're expecting it to be different. Where are you plotting these coordinates? Is there a tool where you can see all three coordinates rendered on GMaps at any one time?

Comment: We're developing a CityNotifier with GoogleMaps. Users can notify events on map and I use traffic notifications to draw heatmpap overlays. [Here](http://ltw1306.web.cs.unibo.it)'s the project site.
I use [THIS](http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html) site to check points from coordinates. Do I answer your question? :)

Comment: Yes that all makes sense. Unfortunately I'm about to leave for a wedding party so I won't be able to look for a while.